# Entropy and Probability in Theano

Tags: python, entropy, theano

I have a written a simple python code to calculate the entropy of a set and I am trying to write the same thing in Theano.

```
import math

# this computes the probabilities of each element in the set
def prob(values):
    return [float(values.count(v))/len(values) for v in values]

# this computes the entropy
def entropy(values):
    p = prob(values)
    return -sum([v*math.log(v) for v in p])
```

I am trying to write the equivalent code in Theno, but I am not sure how to do it:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

v = T.vector('v') # I create a symbolic vector to represent my initial values
p = T.vector('p') # The same for the probabilities 

# this is my attempt to compute the probabilities which would feed vector p
theano.scan(fn=prob,outputs_info=p,non_sequences=v,n_steps=len(values))

# considering the previous step would work, the entropy is just
e = -T.sum(p*T.log(p))
entropy = theano.function([values],e)
```

However, the scan line is not correct and I get tons of errors. I am not sure if there is a simple way to do it (to compute the entropy of a vector), or if I have to put more effort on the scan function. Any ideas?

Comment: Theano can't do computation on list. You must update your code to work with ndarray. Do this first with numpy only. This should already speed up your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than the point raised by nouiz, P should not be declared as a T.vector because it will be the result of computation on your vector of values.

Also, to compute something like entropy, you do not need to use Scan (Scan introduces a computation overhead so it should only be used because there's no other way of computing what you want or to reduce memory usage); you can take a approach like this :

```
values = T.vector('values')
nb_values = values.shape[0]

# For every element in 'values', obtain the total number of times
# its value occurs in 'values'.
# NOTE : I've done the broadcasting a bit more explicitly than
# needed, for clarity.
freqs = T.eq(values[:,None], values[None, :]).sum(0).astype("float32")

# Compute a vector containing, for every value in 'values', the
# probability of that value in the vector 'values'.
# NOTE : these probabilities do *not* sum to 1 because they do not
# correspond to the probability of every element in the vector 'values
# but to the probability of every value in 'values'. For instance, if
# 'values' is [1, 1, 0] then 'probs' will be [2/3, 2/3, 1/3] because the
# value 1 has probability 2/3 and the value 0 has probability 1/3 in
# values'.
probs = freqs / nb_values

entropy = -T.sum(T.log2(probs) / nb_values)
fct = theano.function([values], entropy)

# Will output 0.918296...
print fct([0, 1, 1])
```